# How should I handle users loging into multiple accounts in the same session?

Tags: php, web-applications

I want to know how I should go about allowing users to login to multiple accounts in the same session. For example, user should be able to open a tab, logs into Account A, and opens up another tab to log into Account B. I want to also make sure that anything he does in the first tab affects account A only, but anything done on the second tab affects Account B and nothing else.

Here is more concrete example of what I am having trouble with. Let's say there is a JavaScript function called `deleteList(listId)`that is exposed in the global space, that is, he can call this function in the browser console. Now, this user somehow identifies the listId for a list that exists in Account B. Then, he opens up the tab where he is logged in as Account A, and uses the function to delete the list in Account B although he is on a page where he is logged in as Account A.

I know this may not be a practical or real situation, but I want to know, for the sake or learning, how to prevent this behaviour. That is, if I allow user to login to multiple accounts, how can I differentiate each connection(opened tab/window) made by user even in a same session?

Can I create a new session with each unique connection in PHP? Because what I observe is that if I open multiple tabs, they are all identified as the same session.

Comment: I suppose you could serve up a hidden field (with the user ID) on each page to identify the page that a request is coming from...

Comment: @Floris I think it will overwrite the session user_id, once he logs in another account.

Comment: My first answer would be "don't do this", since reasonably experienced users should be able to assume that everything they do to a thing (e.g. an account) will be reflected in all screens under the same user name. However, if you have to do this, and you think you can make the UI make sense, I'd redirect to a URL containing a "link cookie", which you use to differentiate state across your open browser windows.

Comment: What halfer says. This is theoretically possible by not using a session cookie, but adding the session ID as a parameter to each link and request. It's not the expected behaviour of a web app, though, and it's going to be complex to implement.

Comment: @RoyalBg - you are right if he insists on using the session user_id: I am suggesting to do this "instead of" the session user_id. It is a kluge but it keeps things confined to a page, rather than a session. In fact what I am suggesting sounds a lot like halfer's "link cookie", since the form info will be added to the request on submit.

Comment: It's a big security risk, since this input field/link param can be easily manipulated, and have to be secured with signature or something

Comment: As far as i know gmail implements its multi user login by using some sort of array storage. When you swap the login it will bring you to different url based on your account and every operation is performed with that account.

Comment: @Floris, I thought about that, too. I was going to generate a unique ID in JavaScript so each connection can be identified. I can then make sure this ID is not exposed in the global space. Is this similar what you meant?

Comment: @CookieMonster how you are going to check these id's

Comment: @Royal I don't see the security risk - obviously the OP is going to have to have active sessions, and check every action against which user is logged in for a certain session. The question is how he can have multiple sessions in parallel.

Comment: @Floris, I thoguht I can send it to server once page loads. But it actually doesn't work, sorry. It's because on each page refresh JavaScript would generate a new ID.

Comment: From your comments, what I'm trying to do is probably possible, but it seems to be either less secure or going to be unnecesarily complicated. The best approach, I think, is also not to do this. I can justify this by saying that since the same user logged into multiple accounts, even if they want to call `deleteList(listId)` to delete lists from accounts in other tabs, it is not a security risk. I just need to make sure the user cannot modify other people's accounts without logging in as them.

Comment: Obviously you don't have to generate a new ID on each page refresh. "if ID exists in request, use it in response, unless request was for logout; if not, generate new one if request is for valid login" should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I noticed, google handles it by argument in url. The basic idea is that you store a table of user data in `$_SESSION` and not single record.

Let's say you got kept in `$_SESSION` - `username` and `userip` after login procedure, so instead of keeping it directly in `$_SESSION`, you add a record to `$_SESSION[] array`.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = ...
$_SESSION['userip'] = ...
```

to

```
$_SESSION[] = array('username' => ...,'userip' => ...);
```

Ok so after few logins we got an array of arrays of `username` and `userip`.

The second thing is to rewrite url that it would ignore first part:

`/(.*)/(.*)` -> `/$2?user=$1`

From now on, we refer to logged user session like this:

`$_SESSION[$_GET[user]][...]`

That would be it. Of course you may use different rewrite rules, it is just an idea example.

Comment: Then I can login to each user, by manipulating the get parameter?

Comment: No, only to the ones that were logged in from your session. And it is unavoidable. Works exactly the same in google

Comment: `$_SESSION[$_GET[user]][...]` automatically creates session variable with main key which is the `user` from the querystring. So if I request `http://site.com/user=blabla`, it will create `$_SESSION['blabla']`, isn't it?

Comment: No! It is the way you assign users during login, not from url. Url part is for getting session data when user is logged in.

Comment: I'm telling you that if you are checking `if($_SESSION[$_GET['user']]['ip'] == '127.0.0.1'` for example, if I request `http://site.com?user=blabla` your check automatically will become `if($_SESSION['blabla']['ip'] == '127.0.0.1')`. And by assigning `$_SESSION[] = array(...)`, you are setting the first key numeric, not username. So a test with `$_SESSION[$_GET['user']]` you will always have false result

Comment: @FlashThunder, I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but your approach basically puts a user ID in a request URL, and hash it into the `$_SESSION` array? This way, each single connection is associated with the user ID in the URL, and I can differentiate it on the serve side.

Comment: This looks dangerous, as it allows the client to specify the user ID, no? Why not simply pass the session ID?

Comment: @Pekka, but isn't session ID shared across opened tabs?

Comment: @Cookie only if you use cookies to store the session ID. If you use a GET parameter, they won't. However, you'll have to add the session ID to every link and AJAX request then. I think it's not a great idea to do this in the first place. If I as a user want multiple sessions, I open an incognito browser window, or another browser

Comment: @Cookie reading on the various methods PHP can use to pass the session ID: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: @Pekka웃 in url there is an index in session table, not user id. From google: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox <- after /u/ there is zero - means that it is first logged in user... when you log in from another account at same browser, it will be 1 for that user: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox etc...